# Wheatstone bridge BF350 strain gauge to Arduino GPIO HIGH (fast)

Tags: arduino, strain-gage

Looking to use a strain gauge as a trigger (Z-stop on 3D printer). I also have some other applications for this circuit. Essentially, I want the output from the op amp (TL072 - because of high slew rate, c. 16V/us) to go HIGH as soon as the tiniest voltage is sensed on the Wheatstone bridge. I'm told having it open like this is the way to go but want to know if this circuit will work. I've included a trim pot to balance/tune the bridge as I presume I want the output to be as close to zero as possible before it triggers. The BF350 resistance varies between 349 Ohm and 351 Ohm so with trim pot RV set to give 0V on the output with no strain, if my calculations are correct, the voltage should push towards ~±2.4mV. I think the Arduino needs about 1.85V to register HIGH on a GPIO input.

Very new to electronics so be kind!

[image: Fritzing schematic for Wheatstone bridge]

Edit:

Could I use one of the dual op-amps as an amplifier and the other as a comparator? Ignore the value of R3, it was the default and I have no idea what it should be yet

[image: Proposed solution 2]

Comment: I had never seen a strain gauge used as stop limit switch. Maybe there is a reason behind that.

Comment: Probably because it's simpler, and cheaper, to use a simple mechanical switch but where's the fun in that? Gluing a strain gauge to the printer and calibrating it would be too much for a cheaply mass produced part. Anyway, this isn't the only application I have for these strain gauges.

Wondering whether a Schmitt trigger might better suit my needs

Comment: Use a comparator if you want fast rather than an opamp. Have you considered the effect of noise and drift?

Comment: @Kartman, only just reading about comparators - ideally I'd like something that will switch in under 0.1us. I haven't really considered noise and drift yet.

Comment: How far will your 3D printer move the Z axis in 100 nanoseconds?  How quickly can the Arduino react to the signal?  Is 100 nanoseconds a good requirement?

Comment: @JRE - The printer isn't that quick but the other applications I have might be

Comment: Can the strain gauge even react that quickly?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping to find out! It's for a ballistics application

Comment: What in the mechanical domain needs 100ns response? You might want to consider what you really need. Even a bullet doesn’t move far in 100ns.

Comment: That's true, but if you want to measure the speed of the bullet over a short distance (chronograph), a small error makes quite a big difference. For example, over 10cm, a bullet travelling at, say 3000fps (914m/s), has a transit time of 109.367us. To the nearest 100ns (109.4us) that is already an error of 1fps (which, admittedly, isn't much) but with, say, a 300ns error, that equates to 10fps. There are commercial units out there that can measure these speeds (Magnetospeed, for example)

Comment: Do they use strain gauges?

Comment: They do not, but strain gauges are used to measure chamber pressures (https://www.ktgunsmith.com/straingauge.htm). Looking at the graph he's produced, the pressure rises significantly in the first 250ns - I intend to capture this rising edge

Comment: I suppose if I am trying to measure 2 points then as long as the electronics used to sample each point is consistent, the speed becomes less of an issue. The difficulty is measuring two pulses accurately (intending on using an ESP32) so if they both "leave" each comparator at the same interval after each event, then prop delay might not be so much of an issue

Comment: A simple comparator will not work too well due to drift. Thermal expansion of the base metal will cause this. There’s also thermoelectric effects with the wiring.

Comment: Even with a second gauge connected in a different orientation to compensate?

Answer (score 1):

The bridge presumably has a differential voltage close to 0mV +/- some amount with no pressure. U1 has some offset (+/-4mV in the case of the TL072 if it is operating properly, which it is not in this circuit, but more on that later). So  you could  use an external resistor to offset the input so it is in a predictable state before and after pressure is applied.

If you want to use an op-amp as a comparator it needs to operate on the voltage rail available (minimum 4.5V in the case of the TL072). Also the input range and output swing have to be adequate for the job.

The usual advice here is to use a comparator, however comparators are typically not great at dealing with very low input differences- they are optimized for high speed with relatively large input voltages, so they have relatively low gain and relatively large offset voltage limits.

Comment: I hadn't realised that the TL072 needed such a high voltage. Looks like it might be the wrong component for the job. Can you recommend a comparator with a low switching speed? AD790?

Comment: Maybe something like the [LMV76x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv762q-q1.pdf) but the offset voltage is +/-1mV and 225ns prop delay is specified with a 5mV overdrive. Most real mechanical systems are have resonances, at best (i.e. very rigid constructions), in the kHz range so not sure where your 100ns requirement is coming from.

Comment: I need to learn what overdrive means - told you I was new!